# Prove the following claim about real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on [0,1] such that $|f_n(x)| < \infty$ for a.e.
$x \in [0, 1]$. Then there exists a sequence of positive numbers $a_n$ such that $\frac{f_n(x)}{a_n}\to 0$ for a.e. $x$.

Does Borel-Cantelli Lemma work for this claim?

Comment: Is there a typo? Where are the $a_n$?

Comment: @angryavian sorry,I have rewritten